# excel function to search for similar text names to provide value

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, vlookup

I have two spreadsheets that contain some same company names.

One of the sheets has similar names for the same company:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvYq5.png

The above image is an example of a similar situation. As seen the Bob Ice are all the same company just typed differently. Is there a way to use a vlookup function or similar that can acknowledge similarly spelt names and then return the customer number if that is on another sheet.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfNnY.png

Above image shows other sheet. As seen this sheet only has one Bobs Ice, I would like to be able to have that value appear next to all the Bob Ices on the other sheet.

Is there a way to do this? My actual spread sheet has 5409 rows of companies.

Comment: Have you tried using VLOOKUP with Approximate Match? I think it should help you in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your first sheet is Sheet1 and the 2nd is Sheet2.

on Sheet1 c2 enter:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH("*BOb*",B1,0)),VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet1!A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP("*Bob*",Sheet1!A:B,2,0))
```

With the `Match` I am checking if Bob like exist , with `isna` I transfer to Boolean , and 2 vlookups one for exact and on for approximate

You can grab it down to all column.

Comment: Thanks Balinti! I'll give it a go.

Comment: I've screen shotted my actual situation with hope I'll be able to describe it better. What you have suggested seems to partially work which is awesome. Just can't work out how to complete it!

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8obtq3 is my sheet 1, where I have two Academisch, however on sheet 2 http://prntscr.com/8obtyn as you can see I have the customer code but multiple Academish, Is there a way to specify the * * statement so that it looks for similar titles with out me needing to manually type it in? And how to I tell it to grab the code, it appears to be grabbing the customer name not the customer code?

Comment: Also once again thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Lets start on your 2nd question, you can copy paste it (the cell with the formula) . As for your 1st one, it depends on what is the change between those Academish. if you can make a list of those names it can be helpful to build a formula.

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=1B0A4DAA7507CB90!8199&authkey=!AGDqi01IIi0_d44&ithint=file%2cxlsx

Comment: Are those all the unique names? how many distinct approximate names you have?

Comment: What do you mean by unique names and distinct approximate names?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes I can.

Comment: Have commented on the sheet.